# Keep Ajax response on the browser cache So that the next subsequent page use the data

Tags: ajax

For example:-

Page 1 has a link to page 2.

Page2  is going to do an ajax call to fetch the data. For to improve the site speed of Page 2 , we triggered Ajax call in page1
ie.. 1. Either when we click on link
     2. onbeforeunload

When we trigger this call and browser leaves from page1 to page2, browser aborts the ajax call.

Is there a way to not abort the ajax call and browser can keep the response for the subsequent response.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any way to do that, from your description it seems that the transition from page1 to page2 reloads totally the browser.

To have the desire effect you should load every thing in ajax, even the change of the pages from 1 to 2.